# Disable filter programmatically in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, filter, web.xml

Is there any way we can disable filter and filter mapping declared in web.xmxl programmatically in spring mvc?

I have seen that StandardContext class from tomcat api exposes methods to add filter and filter mapping and remove them too.

The requirement is that we need to disable filter without restarting the server.
If there is any way that can be done in spring mvc, I can expose a rest api for the same using which we can enable and disable filters as and when we want.

Any pointers in this direction are highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I guess you could create or extend filters and conditionally make them do nothing else then forward to the next filter.

Comment: Are those filters written by you or are they third party?

Comment: These are written by me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling/disabling a web.xml filter using a Spring profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800916/enabling-disabling-a-web-xml-filter-using-a-spring-profile)

Answer (score 0):

I see as only way to achieve this to have some kind of "disable flag" into the filter code that avoid it to work, even it's not possible to unchain it from the filter's chain. You can create a controller that share this flag via a context attribute, reading it in each filter call and decide to work or simply "pass the hand".
Of course if your filter is already a blackbox in which you cannot change code this becomes impossible.